# how to append id's with the input field?

Tags: php, html

How to append the id's with the input field and send on the other page in PHP?

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="new_quantity[]" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" />
```

any help??

Comment: @YogeshSuthar id for example product id, student id etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<input type="text" size="3" name="new_quantity[<?php echo $product_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" />
```

Channged : `name="new_quantity[<?php echo $product_id; ?>]"`

In the other page

`print_r($_REQUEST['new_quantity']);`

You can see `product_id` as key and `value` as the value of the input field.

Comment: Prasanth Bendra Thnx friend